# Dialog not firing on JSON callback

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I would be grateful if someone could shed some light as to why my Dialog 'dialog-error' is not firing. In firebug, the response is being shown correctly and there are no errors.  but for some reason, dialog is not responding to it. Many thanks.

Firebug response

```
{"boxerror":"Error","box":"191"}{"boxerror":"Error","box":"192"}




submitHandler: function ()
{
  if ($("#USRboxint").valid() === true)
  {
    var data = $("#USRboxint").serialize();

    $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "bintk.php",
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",

      success: function (data)
      {
        if (data.boxerror == 'Error')
        {
          var messageOutput = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
          {

            messageOutput += data[i].box + '  ';

          }
          var $dialogError = $('<div id="dialog-error"></div>').html('<br />Your New Intake of ' + messageOutput + ' was NOT SUBMITTED. You must enter a box number that is unique.<br />Thank you.');
          $dialogError.dialog(
          {
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            title: 'New Intake Unsuccessfull',
            width: 400,
            height: 260,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
              Close: function ()
              {
                $(this).dialog("close");
              }
            }
          });
        }
        else
        {
          var messageOutputs = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
          {

            messageOutputs += data[i].box + '  ';

          }
          //console.log(messageOutputs);
          //$("#USRaddbox").html("<div class='successMessage'>is a valid e-mail address. Thank you.</div>");
          $("#USRboxint").get(0).reset();
          var $dialogSuccess = $('<div id="dialog-success"></div>').html('<br />Your New Intake of ' + '<b><font color="green">' + messageOutputs + '</font></b>' + ' was successfully submitted.<br />Thank you.');
          $dialogSuccess.dialog(
          {
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            title: 'New Intake successfull',
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
              Close: function ()
              {
                $(this).dialog("close");
              }
            }
          });
        }

      }

    });
  }
}
```

PHP code

```
<?php

    $boxerrortext = 'Error';
    //$error = array();

    $sname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['box_add']));
    $namearray = explode(',',$sname);

    foreach ($namearray as $sname){

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM temp WHERE item = '" . $sname . "'";  
         $result = runSQL($sql) or die(mysql_error());
         $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows > 0) {
         //trigger_error('It exists.', E_USER_WARNING);

         $error = array('boxerror'=>$boxerrortext, 'box'=>$sname);
         $result = json_encode($error);

        echo $result;
    }
    }

?>
```

Comment: If the json string you've added to your post is the correct one it is not valid json.

Comment: How should it be written Tobias. Thanks

Comment: You have to use the array notation like this: `[{"boxerror":"Error","box":"191"},{"boxerror":"Error","box":"192"}]`

Comment: $error = array([{"boxerror":"$boxerrortext", "box":"$sname"}]); Is that correct Tobias. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt look like the div you are trying to create is ever added to the DOM.
I would do:

`$("html").append("<div id='dialog-success' />");
    var $dialogSuccess = $("#dialog-success");
    $dialogSuccess.html('<br />Your New Intake of <b><font color="green">' + messageOutputs + '</font></b> was successfully submitted. <br />Thank you.');`

and then continue on with your code.

Comment: John it says i have 'missing ; before statement. This line $dialogSuccess.html('<br />. Thanks

Comment: John, my bad. Removed the var before that line. no erro but still not firing. I am not sure I have my JSON correct re an earlier comment from Tobias. Thanks

Comment: If you did copy/paste it may have copied some weird character. Otherwise double check all the quotation marks and make sure the correspond correctly when breaking in and out of text. From what I can see, it looks formatted correctly.

Comment: yes, that is bad json formatting. You might be able to parse it anyway. var j = $.parseJSON(data); and then use j.boxerror instead and repalce all the data.xxx with j.xxx

Comment: It is still not firing John. Could it be because of the JSON?

Comment: John I am fairly new to json. Could you please relate your example to my code. Thanks